# PUT end point with [FORMBODY] prefix in parameter not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Below is the controller end point

```
[Route("{id}/cancel")]
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult Cancel(int id, [FromBody]Boolean mail)
{
  //Code goes here 
}
```

when i am calling this end point from Postman i always get value of mail as false.

I specified Content-Type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded it did not worked.

Some where i read an article which said to pass the parameter as "=value" i.e. passing only value not the key, i tried this by passing "=true", but i am again getting the value of mail as false.

Please help.